# What command, if any, can be a good alternative to sublime text's find in folder?

Tags: command-line, terminal, zsh, sublime-text-2, oh-my-zsh

Is there a way to find a string or phrase recursively in all files in a folder from the command line, such that the output would be similar to Sublime Text 2's find behavior? Like, with the path of the filename that the string has been found in and some of the text block that contains it?

Comment: Can you upload an image of "Sublime Text 2's find behavior"?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you are using a *nix system. If you just want the files in the current folder, do

```
$ grep -C 3 foo *
bar.txt-This is line one
bar.txt:This is line two, which contains foo
bar.txt-This is line 3
```

If you also want to recurse into subfolders, use

```
grep -rC 3 foo
```

Details:

```
   grep,  egrep,  fgrep,  rgrep - print lines matching a
   pattern


  -C NUM, -NUM, --context=NUM
          Print  NUM  lines of output context.  Places a
          line containing a group separator (--) between
          contiguous  groups of matches.  With the -o or
          --only-matching option, this has no effect and
          a warning is given.
   -R, -r, --recursive
          Read   all   files   under   each   directory,
          recursively;  this  is  equivalent  to  the -d
          recurse option.
```

Comment: If you have a recent GNU(?) grep, you might want to use also the `--color` option. The filename is then printed in magenta, the matchting text in red.